# Get Data from generic result list and print it

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I using the following code to get data from the JPA but the read call can be for any entity (dynamic call),since the result list is generic but the structure is always the same like this result

```
Person [firstName=firstName 1, lastName=lastName 1, bigDecimal=0, myDate=Wed Sep 16 06:42:18 IST 1998], 
Person [firstName=firstName 2, lastName=lastName 2, bigDecimal=0, myDate=Sun May 19 13:12:51 IDT 1957], 
Person [firstName=firstName 3, lastName=lastName 3, bigDecimal=0, myDate=Fri Jun 03 05:09:20 IDT 1949],
```

The result here is for person but it can be for every entity and the result be with exactly the same structure like
entityname(here is person) and key val like firstname is the key and the val is firstname1 etc

How can i print it from result list like name of the entity and list of key value with the respective data?

This is the code that im using to get the data.

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc");
EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM " + className + " p");

List resultList = query.getResultList();
```

I **cannot** use definition like `List<Person> resultList` because this is related to just Person and during RT I can get any entity like customer ,address,sales order etc .(all the entities is type JPA class) and have the class name and the prosperites of the class name and value

for example here the class is

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a generic String utility that uses reflection to build a string representation of any object.  You would get the list of fields with something like:

```
 List result = new ArrayList();
 Field[] f = <your object>.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
 for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
     if (!Modifier.isStatic(f[i].getModifiers())) {
         result.add(f[i]);
     }
 }

 return result.iterator();
```

and then for each field do something like:

```
 try {
     field.setAccessible(true);
     Object value = field.get(<your object>);
     <String buffer of your generic toString representation>.append(value);
 } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
     // e.printStackTrace() obviously
 }
```

**UPDATE** 
Or, if you like libraries, you can use the ReflectionToStringBuilder from Apache Commons Lang.  I don't know if the default ToStringStyle is what you need, but it's probably easy enough to subclass.

Comment: Be very careful with this kind of approach, because you'll likely get dynamically generated CGLib or Javassist proxies instead of instances of your actual classes when working with JPA entities. You'd better use accessors rather than getting the fields directly. And make sure not to recursively navigate through associations, because you'll have infinite loops, and/or you'll load the whole database in memory.

Comment: @JBNizet-yes I think that this is kind of complicated,do you think that I can use some kind of casting to some array and from there get the data since the structure of the return data should always be the same...

Comment: @JohnJerrby: no. Casting an object to an array will only cause a ClassCastException, since your entities are not arrays. Those kinds of problem are normally solved by polymorphism, by implementing a toString() method in each entity. Either you have to use reflection like suggested here, or you have to test the type of your entity and call a method specific to that entity type to display the data it contains.

Comment: @JBNizet-assume that I implement the to String how should i get the data then from the list,can you please provide simple example?

Comment: `for (Object o : listOfEntities) {System.out.println(o.toString());}`

Comment: @JBNizet- i did it in testing mode but my question is how I print for example just the field or just the values or just the entityname this is something that i dont understand...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print the data in console/log, I think it's as easy as Override the `toString()` method in the Person class.

Comment: Assume that I override the toString how should i get the data for example just for the entity name or just the fields name or values,the print that i provide in my post is from the toString...